# How should browser interpret the same path appearing twice in the srcset

Tags: html, responsive-design, specifications

What the specification says about cases when the same path (or probably the same sized images) appear with different pixel density descriptors?

The following example renders differently in desktop (Windows) Firefox 82.0b2 and Chrome 85.0.4183.121. The image appears natively scaled in FF and half the size in Chrome

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <img src="testpicture.jpg" srcset="testpicture.jpg 2x">
</body>
</html>
```

The reason I'm asking is because a commercial CMS I use very often uses such output. In order to encourage them to avoid this I need a clarification. In this CMS the rendered content works mostly properly in FF, but in Chrome the rendering is sometimes unexpectedly scaled or some image content not appears at all (probably relating to cache availability of different sizes).

---

Update: This is very likely a [chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1132217) when the browser due to internal logic related to caching chooses a wrong variant. But until it finally fixed, I'd rather not post my own answer

Answer (score 0):

The `srcset` attribute is a feature that enable responsive images. Specifically `srcset` gives the browser a hint what resolution images are available. In your case there is only on definition which hints at one image (testpicture.jpg) which has double (2x) resolution. But since there is only one definition, the `srcset` attribute won't do nothing and could be omited.

A full example would look like this:

```
<img src="/files/16864/clock-demo-200px.png" 
  alt="Clock" 
  srcset="/files/16864/clock-demo-200px.png 200w,
      /files/16797/clock-demo-400px.png 400w"
  sizes="(max-width: 600px) 200px, 50vw">
```

Check out the MDN documentation for the [image element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) and their guide on [responsive image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) for further details.

Comment: I understand if my example is ineffective, but I need to know whether it is wrong (in order to file an issue at the CMS bug tracker). Ineffective but formally correct example should produce the same results in browsers. Here is not the case

Comment: Using `srcset="testpicture.jpg 2x"` gives the browser a hint that this picture has double the resolution a normal picture would have. But ff the original images doesn't have double the resolution, the Browser might render it at only half the original size. So in this case it would be much better to omit the tag.